# Formal definition of a function f : Q → Q

Tags: function, math, theory, proof

Give the formal definition of a function
f : Q → Q that is injective but not surjective, or prove why no such function exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized I didn't answer your question - this is a counterexample proving that such a function exists, but it is by no means formal :).

Let's say you're mapping from X->Y.

Injective: for every element in X, you get a different element in Y. If your function is NOT surjective, then not every element in Y is reached by an f(x).

So an injective but not surjective function would be one where (1) there are fewer elements in X than in Y, (2) your mapping is a one-to-one function, where each element in X maps to a different element in Y, and (3) where all the things that you map to from all the elements in X exist in Y.

For example: X={1, 2, 3}, Y={10, 20, 30, 40}, f(x) = 10*x.